# Testing Content Security Policy report-to in localhost

Tags: localhost, content-security-policy, google-reporting-api

I have a report-uri that works well in firefox but Chrome based browsers ignore this property and expect report-to instead.
I have set up a server side api on localhost to receive the browser report http://localhost:8080/api/csp-report-endpoint.
The report-uri works well with this endpoint on localhost.

Now, I want to setup a Content Security Policy with report-to instead of report-uri.
I have used this page as a reference https://developer.chrome.com/articles/reporting-api/
My web app has the following headers successfully set up:
`Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; report-to csp-report-endpoint Reporting-Endpoints: csp-report-endpoint="http://localhost:8080/api/csp-report-endpoint", default="http://localhost:8080/api/csp-report-endpoint"`

I am running my application on local for tests. I have the CSP violation alerts appearing in the browser console but I do not receive any report.
I have checked the API reporting  tab in chrome dev tool and no report is found.
However when I use the network log export chrome://net-export/, I see the reports are in status queued.

I have read that [browser reporting api works on trustworthy secure context](https://w3c.github.io/reporting/#header), but from the w3c documentation, [localhost is also considered as secure context](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/#is-origin-trustworthy)
I have tried the following with no satisfying result:

- run chrome with the flags: .\chrome.exe --short-reporting-delay --allow-insecure-localhost
- use online webhook from webhook.site as report target

At this point I am starting to believe it is impossible to test CSP report-to on localhost. Also [an answer for another related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61529241/22868395) states the same problem when testing on localhost even when using certificate for localhost on https

Did anyone face the same issue and could find a solution ?

Comment: Docs says that `report-to` is not supported on most browsers yet. I'm testing on Chrome with both directives: `report-to` and `report-uri` - does not work on localhost, but with domain it is ok. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-uri

Comment: I've exactly the same problem